# Cannot flag question to migrate to math.stackexchange

Tags: support, stack-overflow, migration

I just wanted to flag a question for migration to math.stackexchange.com. But I could not find the option for migrating to the Math SE. It shows only the following

- meta
- Super User
- Tex
- DBA
- Sharepoint

Do I need more reputation to perform the action? I have 660 on SO.

Comment: Even Jon Skeet with his infinite reputation can't do that, what you need is one small diamond. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal solution for non-moderator users is to use: *flag >  it needs ♦ moderator attention > other*; and describe your choice in the comment box.